# single decimal precision in java

Tags: java, function, format

I have a double such as `32.559`.

How would I get rid of all but one decimal digit so my output would look like `32.5`?

Comment: See java.lang.Math.round and java.text.DecimalFormat

Comment: The lack of own research will probably lead to a lot downvotes ... You should add what you have tried and why it did not meet your requirements.

Comment: Please at least make some research effort next time. A google search with your *exact* title copy and pasted reveals this obvious duplicate: [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
float f = 32.559f;
System.out.printf("%.1f", f);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you just want to print it that way:

```
String result = String.format("%.1f", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DecimalFormat`:

```
Locale locale  = new Locale("en", "UK");
String pattern = "###.#";

DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat)
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
decimalFormat.applyPattern(pattern);

String format = decimalFormat.format(32.559);
System.out.println(format);
```

The output printed from this code would be:

```
32.5
```

This is the Basic above, you can go throws [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) for more details.

Comment: Won't it round it up to print `32.6`?

Comment: This outputs 32.6 for me